# XAMPP Not Starting

Tags: xampp

I have just installed XAMPP on my PC and it doesn't seem to sart. I am getting this error:

```
21:34:50  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
21:34:50  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
21:34:51  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
21:34:51  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
21:34:51  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
21:34:51  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
21:34:51  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
21:34:51  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
21:34:51  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
21:34:51  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change listen port of Apache, open "httpd.conf" file (C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf), then change line:

`#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80`  to

`#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 9000 or other number`

Save and restart Apache Server. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Other programs like Skype use the same ports. If you usually use Skype and you dont want to change "httpd.conf" try to unmark the option in **options->advanced configuration-> connections** that allows Skype, to use these ports .

This was the solution in my case.

Answer (score -1):

two methods:

1-Try to change the default listen port of Apache from 80 to 81, open "httpd.conf" who is in (C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf)

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 81
```

2-on windows try to stop service IIS-2, to do it open terminal with privileges and type thoses commands to stop and start it

```
net stop WAS
net start W3SVC
```

Comment: This really does not add anything, considering that changing the port was already suggested.

Comment: the second method don't modify any port